# Enunciate custom @QueryParam annotation

Tags: enunciate

I am using Enunciate to generate documentation for my Resteasy services. I am able
to generate the documentation needed, but I have an issue regarding some custom parameters.

Our service interface consist of a custom `@QueryParam` annotation which is used to list 
all query parameters the method implementation support. I don't want to explain
now why we decided to have a custom `@QueryParam`, it was just an architectural decision.

Despite all now Enunciate doesn't recognize the custom `@QueryParam` so all my Resteasy methods are without `@QueryParam` parameters (only `@PathParam`).

**Sample service interface:**

```
@GET
@Path("{regionId}/{userId}/validate-access")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@QueryParams(uniqueName = "validatePin", params = {
        @QueryParam(param = Param.PIN, isRequired = true),
        @QueryParam(param = Param.PIN_TYPE, isRequired = false, valueSet = { "valueA", "valueB" }, defaultValue = "valueA") })
StatusResponseResult validatePin(@Context HttpServletRequest hsr, @PathParam("regionId") int regionId,
        @PathParam("userId") int userId, @Context UriInfo info) throws RestApiException;
```

**Implementation of @QueryParam class:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
public @interface QueryParam {
    public Param param();
    public boolean isRequired() default false;
    public boolean canBeEmpty() default true;
    public String defaultValue() default "";
    public String minValue() default "";
    public String maxValue() default "";
    public String format() default "";
    public String[] valueSet() default {};
}
```

**Implementation of @QueryParams class:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface QueryParams {
    String uniqueName();
    QueryParam[] params();
}
```

Is there a way to tell Enunciate to take in consideration also my custom `@QueryParam` 
while generating HTML documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to try using the `@ResourceMethodSignature` annotation to explicitly tell Enunciate what the method is trying to do. [More info here.](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/No-JAX)

You might be able to try applying both the `@QueryParams` annotation *and* the `@QueryParam` annotation.

If neither of those work, the only thing I can think of would be to create a custom Enunciate module that sets up the model that the custom `@QueryParams` annotation is trying to declare. [More (but not much) info here.](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Architecture+Guide)

Comment: The link is broken and now it points to https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/No-JAX

Answer (score 0):

OK, with @ResourceMethodSignature I am able to get all parameters (query and path) in the documentation. The only disadvantage is that I need to list the parameters once again inside @ResourceMethodSignature. If you forget to update also the @ResourceMethodSignature when adding new parameters (or deleted) the documentation will be out-of-sync.

Example:

```
@ResourceMethodSignature(
      pathParams = { @PathParam("regionId"),@PathParam("userId") },
      queryParams = { @javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("pin"), 
                      @javax.ws.rs.QueryParam("pin_type") }
)
```

When you "read" all @javax.ws.rs.QueryParam do you think you could consider also other annotations?